# Объединить все значения свойств объекта в один массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

В функцию записываются данные, нужно вынести в массив только цифры. Формат подаваемых данных должен быть на подобие такого:

```
{"nums":[1,2,3],"a":4,"b":5}
```

/

```
{"same":[14145,341], "2same":77, "also":593,25}
```

Думаю суть ясна

Comment: какой результат ожидается?

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5  как-то так

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = {
  "nums": [1, 2, 3],
  "a": 4,
  "b": 5
};

var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(el => obj[el]).flat();

console.log(arr);
```